# How do I clear Chrome's SSL cache?

Tags: ssl, cache, chrome

I have a HAProxy / stunnel server that handles SSL for our sites on AWS. During testing, I created a self-signed cert on this server and hit it from my desktop using Chrome to test that stunnel was working correctly.

Now I have installed the legitimate cert on that server. When I hit the site from my machine in Chrome it throws the following error:

> Error 113
>   (net::ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH):
>   Unknown error.

My guess is that Chrome cached the key for the self-signed cert and it doesn’t match that of the legitimate cert. This site works in all other browsers on my machine so it’s just a Chrome problem.

**One interesting note:** When hitting the page from a incognito session (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>), it works correctly. So it is clearly some sort of cache thing.

I did all the things I could think of (dumped my cache, deleted certs from the Personal and Other People page in the Manage Certificates dialog, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>, etc.).

My machine is Windows 7 x64. Chrome version: 12.0.742.91.

On the Google Chrome Help Form, there is [a description of what sounds like the same issue](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=685998387b6d8d86&hl=en); however, no resolution is found.

---

**UPDATE:** It seems to have “fixed itself” today. I hate problems like this. I still don’t know what caused it or how it resolved itself. Presumably the cached cert expired or something, but I am still interested to know where this information is stored and how to verify it.

Comment: From another user I heard: 
This issue was caused on my machine by a slightly outdated Avast Antivirus.  Avast creates a layer between your browser and the web with an SHA1 certificate.  If you disable avast for a moment, Chrome will be able to access the certificate delivered by your server.  In my case, a simple Avast Program Update solved the issue.

Comment: This was not the case on my machine as I didn't have anti virus installed.

Comment: Since the question is locked I can't add an answer, but in windows you have to 1) Go to Settings => Manage Certificates => delete the cert then 2) Close Chrome and then 3) Go to task manager and manually kill all of the Chrome.exe processes. Once you open Chrome again you should be good to go.

Comment: @jakejgordon -- I wasn't able to see the cert in the Manage Certificates window, but killing Chrome.exe and reopening Chrome did the trick for me. Note, I have a web filter/monitoring proxy running as well, but did not need to stop it.

Comment: Why is this question "protected" when there are no valid or working answers? @Michael-Hampon?

Comment: On OS X, simply restarting chrome (right click, quit, open it again) fixed my cached SSL cert issue.

Comment: I also cannot add an answer but for Chrome it is called HSTS and can be found navigating to chrome://net-internals/#hsts There you can query by domain and delete the cached certificate

Comment: @NickG: because mods. The only solution that worked for me was restarting Chromium. (Ubuntu)

Comment: Thank you, @Foovanadil — Avast was indeed the culprit for me. Specifically, what worked for me (macOS 10.13.6, Chrome 78, Nov 2019) was to disable Avast's Web Shield, hard refresh the page in Chrome, then turn on Web Shield again.

Comment: Not enough rep to answer...  but what worked for me - go to `chrome://net-internals/#hsts`, enter and delete domain via *Delete domain security policies* at bottom, then restart chrome

Answer (score 42):

Chrome stores SSL certificate state per host in browser history.

So just clear browser history (`Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Del`), at least the following parts:

- Cached images and files
- Hosted app data
- Content licenses
- Cookies and other site data, for Chrome version 64

**Solution 2.** If the above doesn't help, try this:

- Close Chrome, kill all `chrome` background processes
- Delete the directory:
  `%USERPROFILE%/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/CertificateTransparency`

Comment: My problem is ancient now so chrome may have have change this behavior but it didn't work for me to clear the cache (as I noted in the question). If it works now that would be great.

Comment: This did NOT work for me

Comment: This worked for me, my specific problem was that Chrome was saying that the certificate had expired, but since others could access the site on https, I could see that there was indeed a new certificate available, but for some reason Chrome wasn't requesting it, or possibly reading it properly.

Comment: This worked for me in a case where chrome had forcing a particular hostname to HTTPS because I mistakenly tried to fetch it with HTTPS once (the site in question only serves HTTP)

Comment: **FIDDLER users**:  If you are using Fiddler with HTTPS intercepts, fiddler will cache SSL certificates. To fix this, you need to run fiddlers "Remove Interception Certificates" option, clear your browser's  cache (no need to clear anything else, and **restart the browser**.  Depending on which browser you're using, the last two steps might not be needed, but these are needed for Chrome

Comment: Sad that I've searched the whole internet and didn't get working solution. But finally tried it out myself. Close Chrome and delete the directory "CertificateTransparency" under "C:/Users/<your-user-name>/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data" and restart, then you'll find the prompt appear again.

Comment: @ShouYa I have searched for hours and this solves the problem!

Comment: none of these options are working for me. The only solution i found was rebooting the computer

Answer (score 27):

In Windows:

Internet Options/Properties > Content > Clear SSL state

[image]

Then type in any address bar: `chrome://restart`

You don't need to clear your entire history.

Comment: This needs more upvotes as is the only proper answer. Restarting chrome via ```chrome://restart``` also preserves tabs. Amazing! (And 10 years late). Confirmed on Win 11 / Chrome 105

Comment: Just the `chrome://restart` worked for me

Comment: If this worked, it doesn't now. Thanks, Google.

Comment: Works for me, Chrome Version 112.0.5615.86. This should be marked as correct answer. +1!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Just the `chrome://restart` was enough.

Comment: 2023 now and still relevant. +1000 for the chrome://restart hack too.

Comment: Using the `chrome://restart` works for me. Thanks

Answer (score 15):

Many problems with SSL certificates can be solved by simply removing the file from the cache folder.

In Chrome or Chromium, the file to be removed is `cert9.db` in the folder `~/.pki/nssdb`. (In Firefox, you’d want to remove `cert8.db`.)

**Attention!** After removing these files, you will need to re-register CAs in your browser.

This is solution is for linux systems, the steps for Windows users would be somewhat different.

Comment: It would be good if you could elaborate or provide links regarding re-registering CAs.

Comment: It seems that quitting and restarting chrome works after this

Comment: `~/.pki` folder doesn't exist for me (on `Mac`) - and lack of explanation about re-registering CAs seems like a big oversight. Also, "on Windows, somewhat different" is not particularly helpful; if you don't know how to fix it for Windows, just say "this is a *nix-only solution"

Comment: This worked for me, thanks! Ubuntu 18.04 / Linux.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, certificates are not specific to Google Chrome (at least on Windows) but to the whole system. You’ve already deleted that cert through Chrome’s interface, so it should gone.

Just to be certain, you could try.

> Start → Run → `certmgr.msc`

Another tool to try is [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/CCLEANER). It should help with better cleaning of Chrome’s caches.

Comment: Tried certmgr.msc and I don't see the cert in there. Like you said it is clearly gone since the other browsers do the right thing, maybe this is just a chrome bug of some sort

Comment: So ... did you had any luck so far? Have you tried CCleaner as suggested? .. or any other tool?

Comment: I ran CCCleaner and looked at what it wanted to delete and it was nothing more than what Chrome will delete (Just cookies and session info).

Comment: if that is true, why incognitive mode works?

Answer (score 3):

For Windows 10, there is a way to clear only OCSP and CRL information without clearing Chrome history.

More details can be found from Mr. Dimcev's blog post
http://www.carbonwind.net/blog/post/Viewing-clearing-and-disabling-the-OCSP-and-CRL-cache-on-Windows-7.aspx

Running the suggested `certutil -urlcache ocsp delete` is likely to result in `FAILED: 0x80070020 (WIN32: 32 ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION)` if Chrome is running.

Comment: This was the solution that worked for me and enabled me to get past the cached certs.

Answer (score 2):

I confirmed this worked for me on Windows 10:

1. *Pre-requisite: Certify (use another computer with no "knowledge" of your site) that your server serves the new certificate to brand new computers, at least.*
2. Clear the cache of Chrome. I chose to clear all three options presented when using CTRL+SHIFT+DEL: History, Cookies, and Cached. However, you can probably keep your history.
3. **Close chrome**, and using the Task Manager, certify that there is no chrome.exe running. *I think chrome caches the certificate in memory.*
4. Re-open chrome and visit the site. Your chrome browser should now pull the latest certificate and not use the cached one.

Comment: Wiping entire history seems way too powerful method to remove OCSP-info for a single site. Is there really no alternative?

Comment: @JariTurkia, I bet you could actually keep your history. I've updated my answer to suggest this. Your answer could still be helpful for users who want to keep all their cached site data.

Answer (score 0):

Given quite a lot of complicated and incorrect answers:
Chrome caches certificates and does not have an option to remove them.
However you can just force it to get a new one, for example if the website is "www.domain.com" you open "domain.com".
This will make Chrome re-download the (same) certificate which then refreshes both.

Comment: This isn't true. Not every certificate works for both www. and no www. domains. A single-domain certficate could be either one and servers can be configured to serve either one or both.

Comment: Also not every webserver does have a www domain or the domain without configured, also not every DNS has both variants resolving.
In the majority of cases this will work fine, I've been using it all my life.
Alternatively you can still go and close Chrome, remove the cache files manually, start Chrome again.

Answer (score -3):

**More accurate way:**

Ctrl+Shift+Del ( or Settings > Advanced > Clear browsing data )

[ Time range: All time ]

- Chached images and files

press: **Clear data**

Comment: the OP already said he cleared his cache, so for this 7 years old question this answer will not help the op.